# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred with closures

Tags: swift, generics

I have a static function below that will perform a `GET` request and then attempt to parse the data into whatever `<T>` is.

```
public static func get<T>(url: NSURL, paramaters: [String : AnyObject]?, paramaterEncoding: ParameterEncoding, compleation:(response: Response<T>) -> Void)
```

My question is how do I call it?

If I attempt to call it like below I get the error of `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://g.co")!
typealias JsonResponse = [String : AnyObject]
Notwork.get<JsonResponse>(url, paramaters: nil, paramaterEncoding: ParameterEncoding.json) { (response) in }
```

From looking around functions like these normally get their type from the variable that the function returns to just like the example below.

```
let result: Response<JsonResponse> = Notwork.get(url, paramaters: nil, paramaterEncoding: .json)
```

However as the result comes back in a closure, how do I specify what `<T>` is?

Thanks

---

## Edit

Below is some sample code that depicts the same problem.

```
import Foundation

struct My {
    static func function<T>(compleation:(response: T) -> Void) {

        let apiResponse = ["some" : "value"]

        guard let value = apiResponse as? T else {
            return
        }

        compleation(response: value)
    }
}

//Gives error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
My.function { (response) in

}
```

Comment: show us the implementation of the `get` function

Comment: @RMenke I have added an example that shows the same issue as the get method has other things in there that aren't related to this question such as parameter encoding ect.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the type when calling the function. If you are expecting String then call it with String type.

```
MyClass.myFunction { (response: String) in

}
```